# How to get the current Letter at cursor position toString in java?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the current letter in EdiText to String, I tried using some ways but without success, because I'm beginner and still learning.

what I want exactly is to insert special char after every written special char (in onTextChanged event), after get it into String to use (if ...equals ...)

```
String selected = edittext1.getText().toString().substring(startSelection);

  Editable editAble = edittext1.getEditableText();
    
  int start = edittext1.getSelectionStart();
    
    if (selected.equals("(")) {
        
        editAble.insert(start, ")");
        
    }
```

this code not working.
any suggestions ?

Comment: You can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) for this.